# Best way to convert an IEnumerable<T> to an T[]

Tags: arrays, collections, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, ienumerable

What is the best way to convert from a generic `IEnumerable<T>` implementation to an array of T?  The current solution I have looks like the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = getFoo();
string[] bar = new List<string>(foo).ToArray();
```

The transfer through a `List<T>` seems unneccesary, but I haven't been able to find a better way to do it.

Note: I'm working in C# 2.0 here.

Comment: In 3.5 you could do getFoo().ToArray(), that doesn't help you much though :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### .NET 3.0 and after:

Call the [`ToArray` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) on `IEnumerable<T>`, it does nearly the same as below, performing type sniffing and some other optimizations.

### .NET 2.0 and before:

Generally speaking, using a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which will be initialized with the [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and then calling [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) is probably the easiest way to do this.

The [constructor for `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) will check the `IEnumerable<T>` to see if it implements [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) to get the count of items to properly initialize the capacity of the list.  If not, it will expand as normal.

Of course, you might end up creating a number of `List<T>` instances just for the purpose of transforming `IEnumerable<T>` to `T[]`.  To that end, you can write your own method, but you would really just be duplicating the code that exists in `List<T>` already.

Comment: True. If you have the count from another source, though, and not from the IEnumerable<>'s other interfaces (like ICollection), you should use your count to create an array yourself. Any other way, passing through a list would probably be best.

Answer (score 5):

Doing a little .NET Reflector it looks like the Linq ToArray extension method basically does the same thing as passing the IEnumerable through a List<>. The Buffer class is an internal, but the behavior seems very similar to List<>.

```
public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    Buffer<TSource> buffer = new Buffer<TSource>(source);
    return buffer.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// src is IEnumerable<T>
// target is T[]
target = src == null ? new T[] {} : src.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no way to determine the length of the array, then that's the best way.

There's nothing in IEnumerable that will let you determine the length, but perhaps your code has a way of finding out another way. If so, use that to construct an array.